# Find out current linux runlevel in Python script

Tags: python, linux, runlevel

I was wondering what is the best way (if there's any) of knowing what [run-level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Linux_Standard_Base_specification) I (well... my Python script) is in. (You know... 0--> Halting, 1--> Single user, 2345--> Kind of regular run, 6 --> Rebooting)

I've been taking a look to the `os, sys` and `subprocess` libraries, but none of them seem to have anything that returns the run-level of execution.

I know I can execute the system's `runlevel` command, but I would be surprised if Python didn't have something more... "native" for it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Runlevel is not a part of POSIX, and is a distro level thing.

Comment: There is no native python library for that, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are stuck using the 'runlevel' command, nothing native for Python. The result would be useless anyway, because it dependents on the distribution. Some distributions implement an other meaning to the same number. So no standardization in this area.